# Print unsigned int (base 10 / decimal) value of MPI

Tags: c, encryption, libgcrypt

I'm trying to confirm/get the unsigned int (base 10 / decimal) value of an hex'd mpi value. I'm using the following code:

```
#include <gcrypt.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static gcry_mpi_t privkey = NULL;

int main(){

    char *parmstr = "48BFDA215C31A9F0B226B3DB11F862450A0F30DA";

    printf("starting program\n");

    gcry_mpi_scan(&privkey, GCRYMPI_FMT_HEX, (char *)parmstr, 0, NULL);

    printf("printing hashed (?) mpi\n");
    gcry_mpi_dump(privkey);
    printf("\n");

    size_t gablen;
    unsigned char *result;
    /* get length */
    gcry_mpi_print (GCRYMPI_FMT_USG, NULL, 0, &gablen, privkey);
    result = gcry_malloc_secure(gablen);
    /* get actual value */
    gcry_mpi_print (GCRYMPI_FMT_USG, result, gablen, NULL, privkey);

    /* print actual value */
    printf("result: %s\n", result);

    printf("finished\n");
}
```

and i'm getting the following result:

```
    $ ./foo
    starting program
    printing hashed (?) mpi
     48BFDA215C31A9F0B226B3DB11F862450A0F30DA
    result: H¿Ú!\1©ð²&³ÛøbE
0Ú
    finished
```

I would the 'result: ' line to print the actual unsigned int (base 10 / decimal) value.

The private key is taking from the Off-The-Record Pidgin plug-in that i'm trying to work with.

*EDIT*:

can anybody confirm that the actual unsigned int (base 10 / decimal) value should be

> 415325779662433871844955547383752003988573073626

I could probably update the program to create a new mpi in gcrypt with this value and see if the HEX value is the same as what i already have. I will do this later today.

*EDIT 2*:

So i'm trying to do the following to print the HEX value of the int value mentioned above. Something is going wrong:

```
gcry_mpi_t cript_prime;
char buffer[50] = {0};
char number[50] = {0};

cript_prime = gcry_mpi_new(50);

strcpy(number,"415325779662433871844955547383752003988573073626");
gcry_mpi_scan(&cript_prime,GCRYMPI_FMT_USG,number,sizeof(number),NULL);

gcry_mpi_print(GCRYMPI_FMT_USG,buffer,sizeof(buffer),NULL,cript_prime);

printf("The number tested is: %s\n",buffer);

printf("trying to convert to HEX\n");

/* get actual value */
gcry_mpi_print (GCRYMPI_FMT_HEX, buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL, cript_prime);
/* print actual value */
printf("result: %s\n", buffer);
```

The output is:

```
result: 48BFDA215C31A9F0B226B3DB11F862450A0F30DA
The number tested is: 415325779662433871844955547383752003988573073626
trying to convert to HEX
result: 415325779662433871844955547383752003988573073626
```

*EDIT 3*:

I updated the post a bit, basically i'm trying to print the base10 decimal value of an hex value that is generated by the gcrypt library. I'm looking for this value to confirm an implementation that i made to read these values. I was looking for a gcrypt function to achieve this. It seems that gcrypt doesn't supports this?

Comment: So... you're writing a crypto lib and got stuck on converting a hex value into a decimal value?

Comment: I updated the post, basically i'm trying to get the base 10 / decimal value of the hex'd value that is generated by the gcrypt library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working script, the buffer was too small

```
#include <gcrypt.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    gcry_error_t err;
    gcry_mpi_t cript_prime;
    unsigned char buffer[401] = {0};
    char number[101] = {0};

    cript_prime = gcry_mpi_new(101);

    strcpy(number, "415325779662433871844955547383752003988573073626");
    gcry_mpi_scan(&cript_prime, GCRYMPI_FMT_USG, number, sizeof(number), NULL);

    err = gcry_mpi_print(GCRYMPI_FMT_USG, buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL, cript_prime);

    if (err != 0){
      printf("error: %d\n", err);
      return -1;
    }

    printf("The number tested is: %s\n",buffer);

    printf("trying to convert to HEX\n");

    /* get actual value */
    err = gcry_mpi_print(GCRYMPI_FMT_HEX, buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL, cript_prime);

    if (err != 0){
      gcry_err_code_t code = gcry_err_code(err);
      printf("error: %d\n", code);
      return -1;
    }

    /* print actual value */
    printf("result: %s\n", buffer);

    printf("finished\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I also confirmed my thoughts using this website: http://www.unitconversion.org/numbers/base-10-to-base-16-conversion.html

This will show that hex (base-16) 48BFDA215C31A9F0B226B3DB11F862450A0F30DA actual is 415325779662433762080404206464628666084640806848 (base-10)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> result[1] = (gablen >> 24) & 0xff;
> ```

This line puts a nul byte into the byte at offset 1 into `result`.  I don't see where you ever initialize the byte at offset zero, but the bytes at offsets 2 and later are past the end of the string you've constructed.  The string it's formatting starts at result+5, so that's what you should print here:

> ```
> gcry_mpi_print (GCRYMPI_FMT_USG, result + 5, gablen, NULL, privkey);
> ...
> printf("result: %s\n", result + 5);
> ```

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I updated the example. It now prints 'garbage'. I'm looking for an actual number to be printed.

Comment: Well, \x48 is an H, \x21 is a !, so it looks very much like `FMT_USG` is just copying the binary values, i.e. "integer" doesn't mean "printable integer" but "binary integer".

Comment: Thanks, i wrote an example app in C# parsing that data and got the result as mentioned in the edit. I will update my program and see if this matches.

Comment: I updated my post with an example to convert an int value to HEX, sadly this is not working.